# Getting 401 response in google developer api only when query GET subscriptions

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, android-billing

I'm using Google Play Android Developer API. I access it from server with service account. I have private key and got access token with it.

I use scope https://www.googleapis.com/auth/androidpublisher. And when I ask [subscription info](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/subscriptions/get), I got 401 error:

```
"error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "androidpublisher",
    "reason": "permissionDenied",
    "message": "The current user has insufficient permissions to perform the requested operation."
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "The current user has insufficient permissions to perform the requested operation."
 }
```

But when I use other queries **with the same token** and **with the same scope**, I got successfull responses. For example, I can successful get [voided purchases list](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/voidedpurchases/list) or [info about inapp product](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/inappproducts/get):

```
200 OK
{
     "packageName": "com.myapp.exapmle",
     "sku": "subscr_month",
     "status": "active",
     "purchaseType": "subscription",
     "defaultPrice": {
      "priceMicros": "149000000",
      "currency": "RUB"
}
```

What could be the cause of the problem? I added this service account to developer console and provided all permissions (administrator access).

Comment: did you find any solution??

Comment: @shyam I wait 1-2 days after I ask this question. And after this api started working correctly. I think that the cause of the problem is that it is necessary to wait several days before all methods of api starts working correctly. But I not found this in docs.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. Just had to wait a couple days. If you want to add that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Actually the message and the http code are confusing. If the problem is that you have insufficient  permissions as the message says then it should be a 403. I cannot be sure if I'm doing the auth correctly because I'm getting a 401